# How to change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-datepicker

I am using [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) library. I am having trouble converting the date format. When I pick a new date it should display date in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried writing ui-date-format="DD, d MM, yy" in directive element but not working

Comment: try ui-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" and see what happens.

Comment: nothing happened ..it is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ui-date-format="dd/mm/yy" .../>
```

EDIT:

If you want the date on the input to appear in `dd/mm/yy` format as well, you need to init `dateOptions` with the format:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
}
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" ui-date-format="dd/mm/yy" ng-model="ngModel" ui-date="dateOptions"/>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sc9qjak/1/)

Comment: But I want the date selected should appear in dd/mm/yyyy format in textbox itself